# RabbitMQ Server How to connect xamarin forms,i am getting time out exception?

Tags: c#, xamarin

RabbitMQ Server How to connect xamarin form,i getting time out exception?

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

factory.UserName = "*********";
factory.Password = "*******";
factory.VirtualHost = "/";
factory.Protocol = Protocols.DefaultProtocol;
factory.HostName = "*********";
factory.Port = 5672;
```

> {RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable Connection failed ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.}

Comment: What are you having trouble understanding? The exception clearly states that none of the endpoints responded before a timeout occured. Check that you can actually reach your endpoints from where the application is executed

Comment: @fredrik I have written a sample program in .Net core to check the connectivity to RabbitMq and connection got established. But when i'm trying with Xamarin Forms facing above issue.

Comment: Can the device the Forms application is running on ping the hostname the RabbidMQ server is located on?

Comment: @fredrik Thanks for your advice . Now i can able to connect RabbitMQ server from device also.